# Get classwork status

Tags: node.js, google-classroom

Using nodejs (eventually react native), I am working on retrieving classwork that has not been submitted yet. I get the output from the classwork API but there is no field that I can find that tells you the status of the assignment (graded, assigned, turned in, etc). Is there a specific endpoint that I have to call on each classwork to get the status? For reference, here is the output I get (id values have been censored):

```
{

  courseId: '************',

  id: '****',

  title: 'HTWH Syllabus Acknowledgement Form',

  materials: [Array],

  state: 'PUBLISHED',

  alternateLink: 'https://classroom.google.com/c/.......',

  creationTime: '2020-08-26T22:10:25.522Z',

  updateTime: '2020-08-26T22:15:26.587Z',

  dueDate: [Object],

  dueTime: [Object],

  maxPoints: 5,

  workType: 'ASSIGNMENT',

  submissionModificationMode: 'MODIFIABLE_UNTIL_TURNED_IN',

  creatorUserId: '*******',

  topicId: '********'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using [courses.courseWork.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/get) in checking your course work status which will return a [CourseWork](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#CourseWork) instance that doesn't contain the submission state of the course work.

You need to use [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list) if you want to check the submission state of your course work per student. If you want to check a particular student, you can use [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/get).

This will return a [StudentSubmission](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#StudentSubmission) instance, which contains a [submission state](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions#submissionstate) and the `assignedGrade` (if applicable)

[image]

### Sample Response:

Example: I created course work which is assigned to 2 student then check the submission state using [courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list)

```
{
  "studentSubmissions": [
    {
      "courseId": "2371163xxxx",
      "courseWorkId": "30629017xxxx",
      "id": "Cg4IwNPyqfMGEK_pxxxxx",
      "userId": "1043405157872289xxxxx",
      "creationTime": "2021-03-22T21:17:51.331Z",
      "updateTime": "2021-03-22T21:17:51.253Z",
      "state": "CREATED",
      "alternateLink": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "courseWorkType": "ASSIGNMENT",
      "assignmentSubmission": {},
      "submissionHistory": [
        {
          ....
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "courseId": "2371163xxxx",
      "courseWorkId": "30629017xxxx",
      "id": "Cg4I2ujEgvUIEK_pxxxxx",
      "userId": "1112235452378899xxxxx",
      "creationTime": "2021-03-22T21:17:44.380Z",
      "updateTime": "2021-03-22T21:17:44.354Z",
      "state": "CREATED",
      "alternateLink": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "courseWorkType": "ASSIGNMENT",
      "assignmentSubmission": {},
      "submissionHistory": [
        {
          ....
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I am specifically trying to get the work for me in google classroom. Will this endpoint work for that? I am not the teacher in this situation and merely want to get the assignments that I have not submitted. I am using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly
` scope

Comment: This method works with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly` scope. It returns only your submission and not other students when using the scope.